# Performance of multiple iterations

Tags: python, performance, iteration

Wondering about the performance impact of doing one iteration vs many iterations. I work in Python -- I'm not sure if that affects the answer or not.

Consider trying to perform a series of data transformations to every item in a list.

```
def one_pass(my_list):
    for i in xrange(0, len(my_list)):
        my_list[i] = first_transformation(my_list[i])
        my_list[i] = second_transformation(my_list[i])
        my_list[i] = third_transformation(my_list[i])
    return my_list

def multi_pass(my_list):
    range_end = len(my_list)
    for i in xrange(0, range_end):
       my_list[i] = first_transformation(my_list[i])

    for i in xrange(0, range_end):
       my_list[i] = second_transformation(my_list[i])

    for i in xrange(0, range_end):
       my_list[i] = third_transformation(my_list[i])

    return my_list
```

Now, apart from issues with readability, strictly in performance terms, is there a real advantage to one_pass over multi_pass? Assuming most of the work happens in the transformation functions themselves, wouldn't each iteration in multi_pass only take roughly 1/3 as long?

Comment: If most of the work happens in the transformation functions, then you've answered your own question - there is no efficiency advantage to the single-pass approach. BTW, if in doubt, measure!

Comment: BTW, it should probably be `xrange(len(my_list))`, without the subtraction of one. `xrange` produces closed-open intervals by default.

Comment: @user4815162342 -- you are right about xrange().  Made that correction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference will be how often the values and code you're reading are in the [CPU's cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache).

If the elements of `my_list` are large, but fit into the CPU cache, the first version may be beneficial. On the other hand, if the (byte)code of the transformations is large, caching the *operations* may be better than caching the data.

Both versions are probably slower than the way more readable:

```
def simple(my_list):
    return [third_transformation(second_transformation(first_transformation(e)))
            for e in my_list]
```

[Timing it](http://ideone.com/tA57u2) yields:

```
one_pass: 0.839533090591
multi_pass: 0.840938806534
simple: 0.569097995758
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're considering a program that can easily be one loop with multiple operations, or multiple loops doing one operation each, then it never changes the computational complexity (e.g. an O(n) algorithm is still O(n) either way).

One advantage of the single-pass approach are that you save on the "book-keeping" of the looping. Whether the iteration mechanism is incrementing and comparing counters, or retrieving "next" pointers and checking for null, or whatever, you do it less when you do everything in one pass. Assuming that your operations do any significant amount of work at all (and that your looping mechanism is simple and straightforward, not looping over an expensive generator or something), then this "book-keeping" work will be dwarfed by the actual work of your operations, which makes this definitely a micro-optimisation that you shouldn't be doing unless you know your program is too slow and you've exhausted all more significant available optimisations.

Another advantage can be that applying all your operations to each element of the iteration before you move on to the next one tends to benefit better from the CPU cache, since each item could still be in the cache in subsequent operations on the same item, whereas using multiple passes makes that almost impossible (unless your entire collection fits in the cache). Python has so much indirection via dictionaries going on though that it's probably not hard for each individual operation to overflow the cache by reading hash buckets scattered all over the memory space. So this is still a micro-optimisation, but this analysis gives it more of a chance (though still no certainty) of making a significant difference.

One advantage of multi-pass can be that if you need to keep state between loop iterations, the single-pass approach forces you to keep the state of all operations around. This can hurt the CPU cache (maybe the state of each operation individually fits in the cache for an entire pass, but not the state of all the operations put together). In the extreme case this effect could theoretically make the difference between the program fitting in memory and not (I have encountered this once in a program that was chewing through very large quantities of data). But in the extreme cases you **know** that you need to split things up, and the non-extreme cases are again micro-optimisations that are not worth making in advance.

So performance generally favours single-pass by an insignificant amount, but can in some cases favour either single-pass or multi-pass by a significant amount. The conclusion you can draw from this is the same as the general advice applying to all programming: start by writing code in whatever way is most clear and maintainable and still adequately addresses your program. Only once you've got a mostly finished program and **if** it turns out to be "not fast enough", then *measure* the performance effects of the various parts of your code to find out where it's worth spending your time.

Time spent worrying about whether to write single-pass or multi-pass algorithms for performance reasons will almost always turn out to have been wasted. So unless you have unlimited development time available to you, you will get the "best" results from your total development effort (where best includes performance) by not worrying about this up-front, and addressing it on an as-needed basis.

Answer (score 1):

You may get decreased cached misses in either version compared to the other.  It depends on what those transform functions actually do.

If those functions have a lot of code and operate on different sets of data (besides the input and output), multipass may be better.  Otherwise the single pass is likely to be better because the current list element will likely remain cached and the loop operations are only done once instead of three times.

This is a case were comparing actual run times would be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would no doubt prefer the one_pass option.  It definitely performs better.  You may be right that the difference wouldn't be huge.  Python has optimized the xrange iterator really well, but you are still doing 3 times more iterations than needed.